# php - Get compressed contents using cURL

Tags: php, curl, compression, gzip, deflate

I need to get content of various web pages. Some of them are compressed using different methods (gzip, deflate, etc). I've searched on the Internet and found the solution for gzipped content:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://games2k.net/");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

However, this only works for a single method. I need a solution that works for as many compression methods as possible (preferably all of them) or at least the most popular two which are gzip and deflate.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Deflated content  is gzippped

Comment: Thank you @Anigel for pointing that out for me. I found that gzip actually uses DEFLATE algorithm. But people always say there are 2 popular HTTP compression methods: gzip and deflate. This really makes me confused. Anyway, I just want to know if **gzip** works for both methods or not T__T

Answer (score 23, accepted):

did you try

```
$ch = curl_init("http://games2k.net/");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

keep the quotes empty

Comment: Thank you very much, @Deepanshu! I seems that leaving the param empty works well for now. I hardly encounter compression methods other than gzip, though, and I'm still looking for more solutions and explanations.