# Reading a url via PHP script results in X5 bigger response then in browser

Tags: php, curl, httprequest, httpresponse, get-request

I am trying to use Cryptsy api with this link: http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=orderdatav2

When I go there with my browser I get 236.2 KB response.

When I use php with curl/fopen/file_get_contents and produce a GET request I get 1.2M response with the same data! (which takes much longer to be downloaded).

I tried to copy the exact headers but still same results.

I suspect it is because the browser is using gzip and php is not?

Any other options? I am chasing my tail with this one.

**The question is what causing this?**

Comment: I'm guessing HTML compression?

Comment: Most likely the compression is the difference, yes. Why don't you simply take a look at the raw data stream, then you know it? Just use a network sniffer or a debugging proxy.

Comment: You have both downloads.  Compare them.

Comment: @AndyLester No, that won't say anything. The compressed data will be decompressed, the result _should_ be the same. That is the intention of a loss less compression.

Comment: Visit the URL with a browser.  Select all/copy.  Paste into text editor.  Save file.  File size is 1.2MB.

Comment: @Yoni Hassin, if you happen to use Firefox + Firebug, you can see if the page served was compressed by looking at Net tab and it's headers (Content-encoding: gzip or similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip"); didn't work for me.

The solution I found is written here [php - Get compressed contents using cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744112/php-get-compressed-contents-using-curl)

```
$ch = curl_init("http://games2k.net/");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

You were right about the gzip :)

Comment: Strange, it should work with `gzip`. According to the manual: `If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent. `

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, your Browser sends the following Header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`.

The Server is checking for the existence of this header, and then compress the output with `gzip`.

Your Browser receives the content and decompress it, if needed.

`CURL` by default, doesn't. You can change this, with this Code:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```

Also note, that this Option takes care about the complete process. You don't have to setup a custom `Accept-Encoding` Header or decompressing. You do not need to handle it.

More Information:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/