# Curl only works in terminal not in php

Tags: php, curl, cookies

Just a simple script to curl to a website to take some data for my hobby project. In terminal it works perfectly but with php it doesnt work at all. I think it has to do with the cookies

$ch = curl_init();

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.pokemongomap.info/includes/mapdata.php"); 

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'fromlat=52.352772543694165&tolat=52.353516320168715&fromlng=6.672205448722025&tolng=6.6761080628386935&fpoke=1&fgym=1');      
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(     
                'Pragma: no-cache',
                'Origin: http://www.pokemongomap.info', 
                'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                'Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4', 
                'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36', 
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
                'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01', 
                'Cache-Control: no-cache', 
                'Cookie: PHPSESSID=5q2naanh8gj85utl2m96erjfa3; __atssc=reddit%3B1; cookieconsent_dismissed=yes; __atuvc=4%7C33%2C1%7C34; _ga=GA1.2.1355385211.1471162927; latlngzoom=19[##split##]52.35314443349598[##split##]6.674156755780354', 
                'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest', 
                'Connection: keep-alive', 
                'Referer: http://www.pokemongomap.info/'
        ));


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);



$output = curl_exec($ch);
if ($output === FALSE) {
    printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n", curl_errno($ch),
           htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)));
}

curl_close($ch);    
var_dump($output);
```

returns 
string(145) "�]��� D���)j�Ûi�Ѡ+4����߅z����d紨)=qW�+G��Am~��f;c�6v��^�nG�u JF�ǜ ����{��T�.9�s����=m 9G���GFU��%�[�/��r3|l#�7��H�)�"

when using json_decode it returns NULL.

Comment: What is your output? What do you mean by "doesnt work at all"? Do you have errors?

Comment: @WuerfelDev small edit :)

Comment: You're not calling `curl_setopt()` correctly. If you want to put all the options in one call, you should be using `curl_setopt_array()`

Comment: thanks for the tip still not working though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PHP manual for curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php), the second parameter should to be a int or a constant option. Try the code below:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.pokemongomap.info/includes/mapdata.php");

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'fromlat=52.352772543694165&tolat=52.353516320168715&fromlng=6.672205448722025&tolng=6.6761080628386935&fpoke=1&fgym=1');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
              'Pragma: no-cache',
              'Origin: http://www.pokemongomap.info',
              'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
              'Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
              'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36',
              'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
              'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
              'Cache-Control: no-cache',
              'Cookie: PHPSESSID=5q2naanh8gj85utl2m96erjfa3; __atssc=reddit%3B1; cookieconsent_dismissed=yes; __atuvc=4%7C33%2C1%7C34; _ga=GA1.2.1355385211.1471162927; latlngzoom=19[##split##]52.35314443349598[##split##]6.674156755780354',
              'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
              'Connection: keep-alive',
              'Referer: http://www.pokemongomap.info/'
      ));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);


    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($output === FALSE) {
        printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n", curl_errno($ch),
               htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)));
    }

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    var_dump ($info);
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump(json_decode($output));
```

I also changed your final execution to get the curl errors and curl_info, since you are using verbose mode, it will help to define what is wrong with your request.

Comment: it still only returns bool(false) injecting the cookie directly as a string also doesnt help :\

Comment: Please, see my new edit and edit your question posting the error output. Since you are using the verbose mode, you will see exactly what you are sending, including your cookie

Comment: your link was missing my url :) I added it and inject the cookie directly see the new edit for result

Comment: I changed my code again and included the `curl_getinfo($ch);`. Testing it in my environment i got the 200 HTTP response, so curl is working fine. Now we need to discover what is that strange return message :-P. Possibly, this mesage is encoded in some way.

Comment: hmm when checking the content length on the website its also returns 145. so its the same only the encoding is really weird. using the curl in terminal is outputing a json if i add the --compressed and i added the solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744112/php-get-compressed-contents-using-curl add this to your answer if someone else searches it curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");